# MySqlConversionException when accessing DateTime field from DataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, idatareader

I have a C# application over MySql, using [MySQL Connector](http://www.mysql.com); I'm trying to make a 
DataReader request, the query executes fine, however, when trying to access a DateTime field, i'm getting MySqlConversionException {"Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime"}

this is the prototype

```
if (dr != null && !dr.Read()) return;

sesion.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
sesion.Usuario = Convert.ToInt32(dr["usuario"]);
sesion.Estado = Convert.ToByte(dr["estado"]);
// doesn't work
sesion.FchCreacion = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fch_creacion"]);
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error sometimes occurs if you have zero datetime values in your MySQL database (00/00/0000 00:00). Try adding this to the end of your connection string:

```
Allow Zero Datetime=true
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few potential gotchas when converting between MySQL dates/times and .NET DateTimes, but there's a [useful section in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-datetime.html) with advice on how to handle the issues.

Comment: @jkw4703: I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest it may be a culture specific error - is the applicaiton on the same server as the DB, and do they have the same culture settings?

Also, is the column definitely a datetime in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a DBNull value.