# ServiceStack ORMLite not populating results from MySQL

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm new to ORMLite in ServiceStack.  I'm trying to query an existing MySQL database.  I've created this POCO to correspond to my table layout in MySQL:

```
[Alias("checks")]
public class Check
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public long check_id { get; set; }
    public long room_state_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? entry_stamp { get; set; }
    public int student_id { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public long check_type_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? check_dt { get; set; }
    public byte grace { get; set; }
    public DateTime curfew_dt { get; set; }
    public int excused_by { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int points { get; set; }
    public string check_class { get; set; }
    public int leave_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime night_of { get; set; }
    public DateTime violation_dt { get; set; }
    public string excused_reason { get; set; }
    public DateTime? excused_dt { get; set; }
    public sbyte imported { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the MySQL table definition

```
CREATE TABLE checks (
  check_id bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  room_state_id bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  entry_stamp datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  student_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  reason varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  comments text DEFAULT NULL,
  check_type_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  check_dt datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  grace tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  curfew_dt datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  excused_by int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  status char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  points int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  check_class char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  leave_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  night_of date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  violation_dt datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  excused_reason varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  excused_dt datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  imported tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (check_id),
  INDEX check_class (check_class),
  INDEX check_dt (check_dt),
  INDEX check_type_id (check_type_id),
  INDEX excused_by (excused_by),
  INDEX leave_id (leave_id),
  INDEX night_of (night_of),
  INDEX status (status),
  INDEX student_id (student_id)
)
```

And I'm trying to get some results using:

```
    public object Get(GetChecks request)
    {
        return new GetChecksResponse { Results = Db.Select<Check>(q => q.student_id == request.StudentId ) };
    }
```

When I test this, I get a table of results with the right number of rows, but none of the data is populated (all fields in all rows are blank or 0, except for datetimes which have a nonsensical date).  How can I find why ORMLite is not populating my POCOs?

UPDATE:

Logging shows a lot of DateTime conversion errors:

```
2016-01-23 15:35:53.5869|ERROR|OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions|MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
```

at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.GetDateTime()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.PopulateWithSqlReader[T](T objWithProperties, IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, IDataReader reader, Tuple`3[] indexCache, Object[] values)

Comment: Does [logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging) show any errors? Did you create the table with OrmLite, i.e: `db.CreateTable<Check>()` or are you trying to map it to an existing table? if so, please provide the Create Table definition used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add [logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging):

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();
```

You'll see the error:

```
ERROR: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.SByte.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeBuiltin`1.<>c.<GetParseFn>b__4_2(String value) in C:\src\ServiceStack.Text\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeBuiltin.cs:line 51
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConverterExtensions.ConvertNumber(IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, Type toIntegerType, Object value) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\IOrmLiteConverter.cs:line 151
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConverterExtensions.ConvertNumber(IOrmLiteConverter converter, Type toIntegerType, Object value) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\IOrmLiteConverter.cs:line 115
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Converters.IntegerConverter.FromDbValue(Type fieldType, Object value) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\Converters\IntegerConverters.cs:line 25
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.PopulateWithSqlReader[T](T objWithProperties, IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, IDataReader reader, Tuple`3[] indexCache, Object[] values) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.cs:line 343
```

The issue is that the MySql ADO.NET Provider returns `tinyint(1)` as a bool so you can resolve the issue by changing it to a `bool`:

```
public bool imported { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response--got logging turned on, but it looks like I'm seeing lots of DateTime errors rather than errors on the string.  I actually originally had imported as a "bool" but when it wasn't working, I tried to build using the ORMLite T4 templates and thats where I got the sbyte from.

Comment: @scotru that's a [MySql data issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/710182/85785) unrelated to OrmLite.

Comment: Thanks!  I normally use [DevArt's provider](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/)  Is it possible to configure OrmLite to use this provider?

Comment: @scotru No that would require creating a new [OrmLite MySqlDialectProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql), the existing OrmLite provider is built for and tested against `MySql.Data`.

Comment: Makes sense.  I like DevArt's licensing terms better is the main reason I'd like to see it.  Adding a "Allow Zero Datetime=true" to my connection string as described in the article you linked to resolved my original issue.  Results are now correctly populated (even with the sbyte)--thanks for the great support!